# Extract OU name from LDAP path with Regex

Tags: regex

I have an LDAP path similar to the one below, I want to extract the text between the first OU= and the comma that follows it, in the example below the text I need is "Support Group". Can anyone suggest a Regex to do this?

```
CN=James Regus,OU=Support Group,DC=Internal,DC=Com
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?  (That would make it easier to answer with some sample code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will put the text between the `OU=` and the next `,` into $1 or \1 or what have you depending on how the language handles such things.

```
/\bOU=(.*?),/
```

(This assumes your regular expression parser supports `\b` as a shortcut for 0-length wordbreak matching.)

I don't know what programming language you're using, but let's say it's JavaScript.  Here's some sample code:

```
var regex = /\bOU=(.*?),/;
var ldapPath = 'CN=James Regus,OU=Support Group,DC=Internal,DC=Com';    
var match = ldapPath.match(regex);
alert(match[1]);
```